# minimum spanning tree remove all extra edges

Tags: python, algorithm, optimization, minimum-spanning-tree

Extra edge- edge made with 2 points, where each point is connected with another edge.
I want to disconnect MST by deleting these edges.
What is the best approach to minimize the weight of new disconnected MST,
or in what order should I delete these edges(deleting one could affect the other)?
My approach is to delete the biggest weight extra edges first?

https://prnt.sc/1xq1msp

In this case, removing 7(CD)-> no more edges could be deleted.
But you could also remove B-C, and then remove D-E which is better solution

Comment: Your question is a bit hard to understand. Are you looking for an algorithm to solve the [minimum-weight spanning tree problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minimum_spanning_tree)?

Comment: I've put an example, i hope its easier now.

Comment: Oooooh, okay. So you only want nodes to be matched two-by-two? So you're looking to compute a minimum-weight maximal matching in the tree?

Comment: It doesnt have to be twobytwo, it has to bi minimum weight disconnected mst, with condition every point has to be connected at least once ! So if both point in edge are connected with another edge, there is no reason that edge exist, because removing them still  both points leaves connected.

Comment: You're right, sorry. So you're looking for a [minimum edge cover](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Edge_cover#Algorithms)?

Comment: Yes, ty so much!

Comment: Do you know any algorithm or method that finds edge cover not by minimum vertices, but with minimum weight? probably np hard problem...

Comment: The paper by Murty and Perin, 'A 1‐matching blossom‐type algorithm for edge covering problems', gives an O(n^3) blossom based solution for your problem of minimum and maximum cost edge covers. It's also included in chapter 10 of [Murty's book](http://www-personal.umich.edu/~murty/books/network_programming/) on Network Programming, along with solutions for related edge cover and matching problems.

Answer (score 3):

Here’s an exact solution with NumPy/SciPy/OR-Tools that uses a kd-tree
to enumerate a sparse subset of edges that can possibly be included in
an optimal solution, then formulates and solves a mixed integer program.
Not sure it will scale to your needs though; you could set setting a gap
limit if you’re willing to settle for an approximation.

```py
import collections
import numpy
import scipy.spatial

from ortools.linear_solver import pywraplp


def min_edge_cover(points):
    # Enumerate the candidate edges.
    candidate_edges = set()
    tree = scipy.spatial.KDTree(points)
    min_distances = numpy.ndarray(len(points))
    for i, p in enumerate(points):
        if i % 1000 == 0:
            print(i)
        distances, indexes = tree.query(p, k=2)
        # Ignore p itself.
        d, j = (
            (distances[1], indexes[1])
            if indexes[0] == i
            else (distances[0], indexes[0])
        )
        candidate_edges.add((min(i, j), max(i, j)))
        min_distances[i] = d
    for i, p in enumerate(points):
        if i % 1000 == 0:
            print(i)
        # An edge is profitable only if it's shorter than the sum of the
        # distance from each of its endpoints to that endpoint's nearest
        # neighbor.
        indexes = tree.query_ball_point(p, 2 * min_distances[i])
        for j in indexes:
            if i == j:
                continue
            discount = (
                min_distances[i] + min_distances[j]
            ) - scipy.spatial.distance.euclidean(points[i], points[j])
            if discount >= 0:
                candidate_edges.add((min(i, j), max(i, j)))
    candidate_edges = sorted(candidate_edges)

    # Formulate and solve a mixed integer program to find the minimum distance
    # edge cover. There's a way to do this with general weighted matching, but
    # OR-Tools doesn't expose that library yet.
    solver = pywraplp.Solver.CreateSolver("SCIP")
    objective = 0
    edge_variables = []
    coverage = collections.defaultdict(lambda: 0)
    for i, j in candidate_edges:
        x = solver.BoolVar("x{}_{}".format(i, j))
        objective += scipy.spatial.distance.euclidean(points[i], points[j]) * x
        coverage[i] += x
        coverage[j] += x
        edge_variables.append(x)
    solver.Minimize(objective)
    for c in coverage.values():
        solver.Add(c >= 1)
    solver.EnableOutput()
    assert solver.Solve() == pywraplp.Solver.OPTIMAL
    return {e for (e, x) in zip(candidate_edges, edge_variables) if x.solution_value()}


def random_point():
    return complex(random(), random())


def test(points, graphics=False):
    cover = min_edge_cover(points)
    if not graphics:
        return
    with open("out.ps", "w") as f:
        print("%!PS", file=f)
        print(0, "setlinewidth", file=f)
        inch = 72
        scale = 7 * inch
        print((8.5 * inch - scale) / 2, (11 * inch - scale) / 2, "translate", file=f)
        for x, y in points:
            print(scale * x, scale * y, 1, 0, 360, "arc", "fill", file=f)
        for i, j in cover:
            xi, yi = points[i]
            xj, yj = points[j]
            print(
                scale * xi,
                scale * yi,
                "moveto",
                scale * xj,
                scale * yj,
                "lineto",
                file=f,
            )
        print("stroke", file=f)
        print("showpage", file=f)


test(numpy.random.rand(100, 2), graphics=True)
test(numpy.random.rand(10000, 2))
```

Comment: Ty so much. In func min_edge_cover, in first for loop, last line. Shouldn't there be min_distances[i] = distances[1], becuase distances[0] = 0, distance from himself

Comment: @PythonNewbie ugh, yep, that's a bug. Unfortunately it made the MIP trivial, and the MIP is markedly slow now. But I applied the fix above.